# Fastest way to learn MDriven?

Tags: mdriven

What would be the easiest & fastest way to learn without experience with code and information systems?

In general, there are many subject-specific words in MDriven, which makes it quite a lot harder to understand how things are intertwined. This makes me think that id have to learn coding and programming as a whole to fully grasp MDriven?

Answer (score 0):

Get your hands dirty - that is the fastest way! Follow along with the many videos and wiki guides https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Starter_Kit

You can start MDriven-Designer from https://MDriven.net and use it up to 50 classes without license. It is a very potent UML tool that also can execute the model you create.

Even if there are new words/concepts to learn they all have a specific meaning and you will understand their relevance once you have the need for them.

Contrary to traditional coding you can get feedback in just seconds - from idea that goes into model to web-app running in Turnkey prototyper in seconds.

Don't understand ViewModels or Actions? Do AutoForms! Then look on how they where created and change them to your liking - this will help a lot I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new series of baby steps videos:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVF9iJ0UDk7fFpL-iG8W87FRYoWuB_44f

I think this is the best way to learn MDriven